# IntelliJ stack trace line number: blue/gray color meaning

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, when console produces a stack trace, some line number links are gray but some are blue (as in picture). What do the colors mean?

[image]

Comment: the blue-coloured ones will link directly to the source code (if found in your project) - the grey ones are likely in one of the libraries being used by your project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes them blue when `Intellij` can find the source, and gray when it can not. try to click on them. Now if they are from a `library` try to attach `sources` from `Project settings dialog`.